# Python in mac and Windows

Tags: python, windows, macos

Is there any difference in python in both except different operating systems?

I mean if i create a python script in windows, will it run the same in mac too? As long as there is same versions of python in both?

My concern is that I don't have any mac devices to try to run it on so just making sure that I am not doing anything wrong. 
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There absolutely no difference between OS. Its a programming lang, only difference would be the IDE you decide to use. Other than that, the way it give O/P to programs is same. Hope it solves your doubt.

Comment: Yes. Eg. for printing any thing or creating a function, writing models etc. Coding part is same. You can use any OS, it wont matter to 'python language', as long as your code is correct.

Answer (score 6):

**There is no difference.**

Python can run on both systems. **However**, you may be using a module that only works on Windows (e.g. `win32api`). You can check your module's compatibility on a virtual machine.

If you would like to compile into an application (`.exe` or `.app` extension), you will need to use [`py2app`](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) and [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/) which requires you to be on the os respectively. In this case, I suggest that you consider Java or [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) since they are cross platform.

Comment: I dont want to compile cause it makes things complicated as OS changes so i am going to give away the script itself.

Comment: Then there should be no problem. Just be sure that there are no os dependent interactions and the correct python version is used.

Answer (score 1):

Found this discussion revelant to your question. Hope it helps.

https://www.quora.com/Can-I-run-my-Python-program-in-both-Linux-and-Windows